# incorrect output of binary search tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I've already debugged the code and did not find any mistake. Below code does not print all the data of binary search tree(BST).Only root node and last two node get display in inorder traversal.

```
struct node{
    int key;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

node* newNode(int data){
    node *ptr=new node;
    ptr->key=data;
    ptr->left=ptr->right=NULL;

    return ptr;
}

node* insert_node(node* root,int data){
    if(root==NULL){
        root=newNode(data);
    }else if(data<=root->key){
        root->left=newNode(data);
    }else{
        root->right=newNode(data);
    }

   return root;
}

void inorder(node* root){
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    inorder(root->left);
    cout<<root->key<<" ";
    inorder(root->right);
}

int main(){
    node *root=NULL;

    root=insert_node(root,10);
    root=insert_node(root,12);
    root=insert_node(root,15);
    root=insert_node(root,1);
    root=insert_node(root,20); 

    inorder(root);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's assume you **first** insert a node with `data = 10` (that will act as a `root`). Then you insert a node with `data = 8`, so its inserted to the left, right? Ok, now you insert a node with `data = 6`. Your root node stays the same, so the node with `data = 6` overrides the node with `data = 8`, if I am not mistaken. Additionally, this creates a memory leak, since the node with `data = 8` is not being deleted and becomes inaccessible

Comment: *I've already debugged the code and did not find any mistake* -- If you found no mistake, why are you having an issue?  If you know that something doesn't work correctly, you have a mistake.

Comment: @Fureeish data is added only at leaf through recursion. when `data=8` is inserted it will be inserted to  left to the root but when `data=6` will be inserted it will be inserted to left to the `data=8` node.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I meant i debugged using paper pen and didn't find mistake.

Comment: No. I just tested your code and it's not correct. If you call `root=insert_node(root,10);` followed by `root=insert_node(root,8);` and `root=insert_node(root,6);`, the `std::cout << root->left->key;` will display **`6`**, which is not what you are expecting - you are expecting **`8`**

Comment: @Fureeish any suggestion where i'm making mistake?

Comment: @ankuselfie -- Then it's time to learn to use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset.  Using pencil and paper to debug something won't get you very far if you *think* your program works correctly.

Comment: My suggestion is to rethink your implementation of `node* insert_node(node* root,int data)`. There are a lot of ways how could you improve it. Simply insert node anywhere and fix the values afterwards / find the correct place where to insert the value and do so...

Comment: I will learn it  @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @ankuselfie Your `insert_node` function should be attempting to search for the correct spot to insert the node.  Instead, it sees a spot at the very start and inserts a node -- that cannot be correct, and you don't need to debug this to see this big mistake.  How would your `insert_node` function work if the node needs to be inserted at the bottom of the tree?  Does that function even attempt to go to the bottom of the tree to insert the node?  Say if we need to insert 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, then 5?  That 5 would be at the bottom node on the left of the tree.  Where is the loop to get to that spot?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks man. got the mistake and will learn debugger tool

Answer (score 0):

The insert function is not having any recursive or iterative implementation that will find the leaf node. So the new node will replace the child nodes of root node. And I think that is very well highlighted in comment section.

Here's a block of code in which the leaf node is located by use of iteration and then the new node is inserted.

```
node *insert_node( node *root, int data){
struct node *ptr, *nodeptr, *parentptr;
ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
ptr->data = data;
ptr->left = NULL;
ptr->right = NULL;
if(root==NULL) //tree is empty
{
    root=ptr;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
}
else
{
    parentptr=NULL; // keep the address of parent node
    nodeptr=root;
    while(nodeptr!=NULL)
    {
        parentptr=nodeptr;
        if(data<nodeptr->data)
            nodeptr=nodeptr->left;
        else
            nodeptr = nodeptr->right;
    }
    // now the parentptr contains address of the leaf node 
    if(data<parentptr->data)
        parentptr->left = ptr;
    else
        parentptr->right = ptr;
}
return root;
}
```

You can also refer to some other sources for recursive implementation of the same.